# blackberry "error file is not a valid java code file"

Tags: java, blackberry

Here I have created an app, and I need to run app in device but using javaloader but it shows blackberry error file is not a valid java code file.

I also found  result on many sites but no more success.

Here is other sites reply is

1.Either main class name is not mentioned in your build script, or if no setting is present in build file, then the main class(UiApplication) name is not same as the cod file name.
2. The JDE version with which the build is done and the device OS version are not compatible.

Both things I do no success... :(

Comment: Are you using any specific IDE?

Comment: @npinti I am using eclipse ide and blackberry jre 5.0

Comment: You could be developing code for OSN while your phone is running on OSN-1, so for instance you could be developing code for OS version 5 while your phone runs on OS version 4.

Comment: but my phone OS version is 7.0

Comment: Maybe you could write a simpler program just to see if it works.

Comment: @npinti Simple app installed successfully. but my project not

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16083/discussion-between-newts-and-npinti)

Comment: So you are using javaloader. What file are you trying to install? It has to be a .cod file and it should contain the sibling cods (if there were any).

Comment: @Mister Smith yes it has 100 cod file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [a declared limit](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/The-maximum-size-of-a-BlackBerry-smartphone-application/ta-p/1300209) for cod file size and qty of sibling cod files. And your application is going to reach this limit.

Split your big application project to one or more `library type` projects and one `application type` project that depends on those library projects.

Comment: My res folder size is 6.94 mb and src folder is 2 mb but total cod files generated 158, its right or not.

Comment: If it is one application, then you have reached the limit. It is allowed max 127 sibling cod files. Split your app to application and library projects. And then compile and deploy. It will give you a workaround.