# Error: file is not a valid Java code file in blackberry app

Tags: cordova, blackberry, java-me

Refered : [blackberry "error file is not a valid java code file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212481/blackberry-error-file-is-not-a-valid-java-code-file)

I have created an app for blackberry...

Every thing is ok

But my client try to upload that app to blackberry directory.... it says an error as

> - While testing your app on the BlackBerry Smartphone 8520, if the user tries to install the application then the user notices that application cod files are not installed properly on to the device.
>     Note: While installing cod files user notices the error message as “Error: file is not a valid Java code file“.
> - While testing your app on the BlackBerry Smartphones 9300, 9330, 9860, 9850, 9360, 9350, 9800 and 9810, the application fails to launch and displays the following error message with an "OK" option to dismiss it: "Error starting `myappname`: Module 'myappname-3' not found".

Comment: How are these testers downloading your application to their phones?  If they are using OTA, then I suspect you have an application that has created a sibling cod file, and so you should unzip original cod. This might help: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/7693/Extract_sibling_cod_files_512523_11.jsp

Comment: @PeterStrange have to rename the extension of the file from `cod` to `zip`

Comment: @PeterStrange thanks for your reply...If possible please come on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45106/black-berry-app

Comment: Rename the file using your OS renaming tool - for example in Windows using File Explorer.

Comment: @PeterStrange I don't know abt the BB app development... My senior did that project but nw he moved to another company...I have some file `myapp.alx`,`myapp.cod`,`myapp.jad`...... which file format will support by BB app world...

Comment: I changed that file extension from `cod` to `zip`....then wht I have to do ???? compress `myapp.zip` & `myapp.jad`....to `myapp.zip` ????

Comment: @PeterStrange Other wise I have to upload all `cod` file along with `jad` file

Comment: If you are using OTA download, then you should unzip the cods, i.e. rename, then unzip.  Put the unzipped cods and jad file on the web site.  If you are supplying to App World you do not need to unzip.

Comment: @PeterStrange Very Thanks !!!!! Let me check !!!!!!!!!!